# Use formula for multiplication?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, listview

I have two fields on a record ("Qty" and "Harga").

How do I multiply the two and save result into another field in a ListView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ListView` control has no built-in ability to perform calculations for you, like a spreadsheet.  It just displays whatever data you give it to display.  If you want it to display the product of a multiplication equation, you will need to do that calculation yourself in the code and then add the result to the `ListView` column.  For instance:

```
Public Sub AddItem(description As String, total As Integer, count As Integer)
    Dim i As ListViewItem = ListView1.Items.Add(description)
    i.SubItems.Add(total.ToString())
    i.SubItems.Add(count.ToString())
    Dim product As Integer = total * count
    i.SubItems.Add(product.ToString())
End Sub
```

Comment: I added an example of what I mean.

Comment: Are you saying that the data is coming directly from the database and is displayed in the `ListView` control using data binding?

Comment: it's not that I mean, I asked if i was doing calculations in a database record, or where I get record? indeed tie up directly from database. so i'm confused to do calculations

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your English.  If you are using data binding, you have two options.  Either you can stop using data binding and populate the control yourself (as I demonstrated above), or you can alter the SQL command that you are using to get the data.  For instance, instead of `SELECT Description, Total, Count FROM MyTable`, you could change it to `SELECT Description, Total, Count, (Total * Count) FROM MyTable`.

Comment: please be advised, i'm indeed a bit difficult to speak English, because of unfamiliar in life :D,, Okay i'm trying your suggestion. thanx u advance steve,

Comment: i've a quetion again,how to fill a column in listview? especially for the one column only,

Comment: I assume what you are asking is how to use data binding to only update one column in a `ListView`, without touching the other columns.  I don't use data binding much, and I wouldn't recommend using it in almost any situation, so I'm not a good person to ask about that.  I doubt, however, that such a thing is possible.  I highly suspect that if you want that much control over it, you'll need to stop using data binding an manually populate the `ListView` yourself.

Comment: to resolve the problem of my calculation, with a  converttoDouble. Second quetion i want to know, if i can want to try expand input from listview, my purpose is just thatm for first quetionn i've found.